# Is it anyhow possible to use 256 bit SSL encryption with IIS7?

Tags: iis, ssl

I developed an ASP.NET web application which handles sensitive data.
I would really like to use 256 bit SSL encryption, but it seems that IIS
only supports 128 bit.

Is it somehow possible to get 256bit encryption?
If not, why not and will it be possible in IIS 7.5 or 8.0?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible on win7/2008 with a bit of [reg hacking](http://derek858.blogspot.com/2010/06/enable-tls-12-aes-256-and-sha-256-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't switch from AES-128 to AES-256. An attack has been found on the latter, that reduces the complexity to an equivalent of 119 bits:

http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/new_attack_on_a.html

Nevertheless, both algorithms are insanely strong for today's standards. There are probably other attack scenarios that are much more likely than a fault on the crypto itself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the AES-256 attack. It's a related key attack and thus not applicable to HTTPS.

But the commenter is correct that both are sufficiently strong that you shouldn't worry.